# Как добавить SESSIONS в форму авторизации?

Tags: php, auth, аутентификация

Вот код авторизации. Да, без mysql. Да, ужасно, но всё же.

```
<? 
    $filename = ("base.txt");

    function AuthForm () 
    {
        echo ('<form method=\'post\'>
        <label>Логин: </label>
        <input type = \'text\' name = \'login\'><br />
        <label>Пароль: </label>
        <input type = \'password\' name = \'password\'><br />
        <input type = \'submit\' name = \'log\' value = \'Войти\'>
        </form>'
        );
    }
  if(empty($_POST))
    {
    }else
{

    $arr = file($filename);
    $i = 0;
    $temp = array();
    foreach($arr as $line)
    {
      $data = explode("|:|",$line);
      $temp['login1'][$i]     = $data[0];
      $temp['password1'][$i] = $data[1];
      $i++;
    }

    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $password = /*md5*/($_POST['password']);

    if(!in_array($login,$temp['login1']))
        {
            echo("Пользователь с таким именем не зарегистрирован. <a href='#'>Вернуться</a>");
            exit();
        }

    $index = array_search($login,$temp['login1']);

    if($password != $temp['password1'][$index])
        {
            echo("Неправильный пароль. <a href='#'>Вернуться</a>");
            exit();
        }
}
?>
```

Вот сама авторизация на сайте:

```
<?
require ("auth.php");

AuthForm();

?>
```

Кто подключал уже себе эту ерунду, помогите, пожалуйста. Уже всё перепробовал.

Comment: Скорее всего, но всё же они разные, в том уже код с ошибкой, а здесь, чистый код, где я попросил помощи подсказать, как будет лучше оформить это.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот код должен быть в начале каждой страницы

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

В массив сессий вы можете занести данные присвоением значения новому елементу массива

```
$_SESSION['newEl'] = 'value';
```

В блоке кода куда Вас заводит submit формы сделайте после валидации логина 
запись в сессию скажем того-же логина.

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
//валидация 
//если проверки пройдены - заносите логин в сессию
    $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login'];
}
```

На остальных страницах при условии прописаного кода старта сессии у Вас должна вардампится эта переменная, по этому условию можете считать пользователя авторизированым и не выводить ему форму авторизации.

Подробнее о сессиях можете прочитать в [документации](http://phpfaq.ru/sessions). Там же описаны частые причины "слетания"сессии при редиректах по страницам.

Comment: нельзя ли, <? session_start(); ?> добавить в auth.php и подключать соответственно?

Comment: можно ещё одну поправочку? очень таки мешает, когда я лично себе ставил if(empty($_POST)) он ругается мол что то уже заполнено.
и не даёт ничего сделать. вылезает постоянная ошибка мол неправильный логин, хотя я только только страницу обновил. Что можно с этим сделать?

Comment: Теоретически можно. Но практически "не круто" подключать php файл ко всем html-файлам (страничкам). Да и по большому счету вам по данному вопросу сессия нужна только для фиксации факта авторизации

Comment: Константин, я вот только зарегистрировался здесь, можно как то связаться с вами? в двух словах бы описал проблему, да и вы очень хороший программист.

Comment: На счет if(empty($_POST)), не хорошая проверка, т.к. у вас этот массив всегда пустой, кроме случая нажатия кнопки Submit. Лучше переделйте на тот вариант что я в сообщении предлагал if(!empty($_POST)) После нажатия кнопки Submit вы попадете внутрь этого if и выполните в теории процесс авторизации.

Comment: я это сделал, по вашему было намного лучше.
но можно всё же связаться с вами?

Comment: Константин, есть ли скайп? или что то подобное? чтобы связаться в режиме реального времени..

Comment: и да, не завелось кстати. всё равно при переходе на другую страницу не сохраняет сессию.

Comment: Эм... Сессию с подобными методами легко затереть. Попробуйте сделать так чтобы с session_start(); в начале каждой страницы, созданая вручную переменная (елемент массива сессии) на одной из этих страниц - была доступна (вардампилась из . массива сессии) на остальных. Попробуйте сделать это без форм и авторизаций.

Comment: ничего толком то и не помогло, сделал даже лучше чем было, оно всё равно так же не заводится.